# how to use AES block cypher when there are only 47 byte space?

Tags: aes

If I have only 47 byte for encrypted data, and want to use AES block cypher, is there a method that I could make full use of them, or if I could only use 32 bytes of them, since the block should be multiple of 16 byte?

Comment: It really depends on how much data you want to encrypt in the first place. If it's more than 47 bytes, then you're out of luck. If it's always 47 bytes or less, then this can be done. If it is 32 bytes or less, then this is really easy.

Comment: If there are more than 32 byte of data, for example, there are 40 byte of data, how can I encrypt it use AES block cypher and fill the encrypted data into a 47 byte space? I guess I couldn't unless use stream cypher or something else...

Answer (score 4):

This is what a [block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) is for:

> ...  A block cipher by itself is only suitable for the secure cryptographic transformation (encryption or decryption) of one fixed-length group of bits called a block.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) A mode of operation describes how to repeatedly apply a cipher's single-block operation to securely transform amounts of data larger than a block.[3][4][5]

You might consider:

- Using an authenticated mode of operation such as [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode)
- Offload all the work to an existing library for whatever your purpose is (PGP for data at rest or TLS for data in transit), which will handle all of these details for you.

Comment: Why using _authenticated mode_ when only encryption is needed?

Comment: @Cryptostasis Encryption seeks to allow only authorized parties to access/make secret pieces of information. In order to authorize a party for anything, they must first be authenticated. With unauthenticated encryption, I can encrypt arbitrary data with an arbitrary key and send it to an authorized party. This means everyone has the ability to encrypt, even if it decrypts to nonsense to an authorized party. This is is a violation of the goal of encryption. Authenticated encryption is what almost everyone really needs, even if they don't realize it.

Comment: I do not agree. Only _authorized recipients_ may be able to decrypt the message. But  this does not imply that the sender must be authenticated. With public key encryption that is completely standard. Think aboutl https encryption, where the client normally doesn't authenticate himself.

Comment: @Cryptostasis Asymmetric crypto is not free from [requiring authentication either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Security). And in https, the asymmetric crypto is used to exchange a symmetric secret, which will then be used to perform *authenticated* symmetric encryption between the sender and receiver. AE implies integrity protection as well... Let me put it this way: why should anyone choose *not* to use authenticated encryption? In what way does it impede the users goals?

Comment: Sometimes, you want to separate both. For instance, when your data shall be  HMAC protected (see TPM). In some ( but maybe rare) circumstances you must not authenticate your encrypted data. For instance, in the first step of the Pace protocol, where an encrypted random number with low entropy key is transmitted ( see ePassport ).

Comment: @Cryptostasis "when your data shall be HMAC protected" - This provides authentication and integrity, which, when applied to encrypted information, yields authenticated encryption. I don't see any reason to modify my recommendation.

Comment: Yes, but you mention protocols where the authentication mode is prescribed. Again, I do not say that authentication is a bad idea. What I wanted to say is, the stated question is with regard to encryption only. And therefore an answer should also regard encryption only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard chaining mode and padding. For instance, [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) would do the job.